# Symfony 5 / Webpack Encore / Bootstrap : javascript no funciona

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, symfony, webpack

Estoy trabajando con Symfony 5.0, instalado con Bitnami wampstack. Instalé Webpack Encore y confoguré el fichero webpack.config.js, también instalé Bootstrap, en ambos casos la instalación la hice siguiendo las instrucciones del sitio oficial de Symfony. Pero el javascript no está funcionando, por ejemplo, tengo un menú donde no funciona el dropdown. En la consola del navegador aparecen las siguientes advertencias:

- El script de “http://127.0.0.1/build/runtime.js” fue cargado a pesar
  de que su tipo MIME (“text/html”) no es un tipo MIME válido de
  JavaScript.
- Ha fallado la carga del script con origen "http://127.0.0.1/build/runtime.js".
- El script de “http://127.0.0.1/build/app.js” fue cargado a pesar de
  que su tipo    MIME (“text/html”) no es un tipo MIME válido de
  JavaScript.
- Ha fallado la carga del script con origen "http://127.0.0.1/build/app.js".

En el fichero assets/js/app.js tengo:

```
    const $ = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap');
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });

    console.log('Hello Webpack Encore');
```

En el fichero template base.html.twig tengo para enlazar el javascript:

```
{% block javascripts %}         
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se solucionó modificando los ficheros manifest.json y entrypoints.json
Anteriormente manifes.json:

```
{
"build/app.css": "/build/app.css",
"build/app.js": "/build/app.js",
"build/runtime.js": "/build/runtime.js",
"build/binocular.jpg": "/build/binocular.jpg"
}
```

Actualizado manifes.json:

```
{
"build/app.css": "/symfony/build/app.css",
"build/app.js": "/symfony/build/app.js",
"build/runtime.js": "/symfony/build/runtime.js",
"build/binocular.jpg": "/symfony/build/binocular.jpg"
}
```

Anteriormente entrypoints.json:

```
{
"entrypoints": {
    "app": {
        "js": [
            "/build/runtime.js",
            "/build/app.js"
        ],
        "css": [
            "/build/app.css"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Actualizado entrypoints.json:

```
{
"entrypoints": {
    "app": {
        "js": [
            "/symfony/build/runtime.js",
            "/symfony/build/app.js"
        ],
        "css": [
            "/symfony/build/app.css"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

En cada ruta, antes de /build, debe agregarse /symfony, esto se debe a que al estar trabajando con Bitnami wampstack, en el fichero conf/httpd-prefix.conf, dentro del proyecto, se configuró:

```
Alias /symfony/ "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.3.12-0/frameworks/symfony/public/"
Alias /symfony "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.3.12-0/frameworks/symfony/public"
```

y el Alias impuesto en este caso fue /symfony, en cualquier caso la ruta debe empezar con ese Alias que fue puesto en el fichero conf/httpd-prefix.conf.